# How to show one product at a time and when the page is refreshed a new product will show

Tags: php, laravel, database

Am building a PTC system using Laravel, currently all the available ptc ads are displayed once.

But I want the available ads to display one after the other.

For example, once a user click on Start button. The first ptcad will display and when the user completes the required task and viewed the ad, refresh s the page or go back to start button. Another ptc ads will show.

This is the current controller that handles the ptc view.

```
public function allAdvertise()

    {

        $siteConfigure = Configure::first();

        $activeAds = Ptc::where('status',1)

                ->where('remaining','>',0)

                ->inRandomOrder()

                ->orderBy('id','DESC')

                ->withCount('todayPtcView')

                ->paginate(config('basic.paginate'));

        return view($this->theme . 'user.ptc.allAdvertise', compact('activeAds', 'siteConfigure'));

    }
```

What do I need to do to achieve that? Or how can I extend the code to get the needed functionality?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: You need to add another table to maintain the ads shown to user or completed the user, while returning the ads you need to exclude shown ads

Comment: If I know how to do that I wouldn't have asked the question, I need help. Or a resources that covers the topic, thanks.